# My LWC test is not displaying code coverage

Tags: salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, code-coverage, lwc-jest

I have configured jest for Lightning web component test. My tests are running and passing but code coverage not displaying into output. Following is `package.json` file: -

```
    {
      "name": "my-project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "Some description",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test:unit": "lwc-jest --coverage",
        "test:unit:watch": "lwc-jest --watch",
        "test:unit:debug": "lwc-jest --debug"
      },
      "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "some url here"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "homepage": "read me file link",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@salesforce/lwc-jest": "^0.5.1"
      },
      "jest" : {
        "collectCoverage" : true,
        "collectCoverageFrom" :[
          "**/*.test.js"
        ]
      }
    }
```

I  used `npm run test:unit` command to run test. and following is my output:

[image]

Please suggest me where I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A similar issue has been reported: https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/40#issuecomment-515343624.

Comment: Thank you @pmdartus, your linked helped me in solving the issue. I will be posting my answer very soon here.

Comment: Sushant do you have an answer to post?

Comment: @KevinHill Yes, I have answer for this question. I will be posting that here soon

Comment: By any chance did you get the solution for this?

Comment: @SushantSrivastava, can you please post your solution here? That will help others who have similar problem

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve a similar problem by setting coverageProvider to "v8" in jest.config.js, like this:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');
module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    // add any custom configurations here
    coverageProvider: "v8"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and was able to resolve it successfully by implementing the following jest.config.js:

```
const { jestConfig } = require('@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config');

const collectCoverageFrom = []

collectCoverageFrom.push('./force-app/main/default/lwc/**/*.{js,jsx}')

module.exports = {
    ...jestConfig,
    collectCoverageFrom: collectCoverageFrom,
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [],
    snapshotSerializers: []
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what your snippet is doing? How is it any different from the standard config file?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira, just to clarify, collectCoverageFrom is used only for convenience in collecting coverage from specific JS files or folders, while covergePathIgnorePatterns helps to ignore certain paths. The main configuration, snapshotSerializers, takes precedence. By default, the snapshotSerializers configuration in jestConfig is: `snapshotSerializers: ['/.../node_modules/@lwc/jest-serializer/src/index.js'].`
Strangely, in my particular case, this configuration hides certain coverage paths.
P.S. I acknowledge the possibility that there may be something I'm not aware of :)